# Get application version in Xamarin.iOS no longer working?

Tags: xamarin.ios, version, xamarin

I'm using

```cs
string version = NSBundle.MainBundle.ObjectForInfoDictionary("CFBundleVersion").ToString();
```

to get my app's version. It is set to *1.2.0*

[image: Screenshot of project settings]

However the code above returns *1.0*. I have already recreated info.plist without success.
I know I used the same code in previous projects, so what changed?

Of course I have already tried to clean and rebuild.

> Xamarin Studio Version 4.1.12 (build 6) Installation UUID:
>   b8bdc5a1-348b-4fad-8e4f-4632ee990c59 Runtime:     Mono 3.2.3
>   ((no/8d3b4b7)     GTK+ 2.24.20 theme: Raleigh     GTK# (2.12.0.0)     Package
>   version: 302030000
>
> Apple Developer Tools Xcode 5.0 (3332.25) Build 5A1413
>
> Xamarin.iOS Version: 7.0.2.7 (Indie Edition) Hash: 57edee2 Branch: 
>   Build date: 2013-04-10 18:05:51-0400

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the Info.plist in the .app and see what's actually there? If the file is stored in a binary format you can use Apple's plutil tool to convert it into readable xml.

Comment: As jstedfast mentioned use CFBundleShortVersionString which will give you somewhat like "1.2.0 (1.0)"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "Version" entry in the UI actually maps to CFBundleShortVersionString just like Xcode does. The "Build" entry is what maps to CFBundleVersion.

Hope that helps.